# element inside a colorbox with an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i improve my colorbox element with an action.
Want to call a new colorbox after cliking in an element on my existing colorbox.

Thanks in advnc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement that sort of functionality is by putting something like this into your document ready function:

```
$('a[rel="colorbox"]').live("click", function() {
    $.colorbox({
        open: true,
        href: this.href
    });

    return false;
});
```

This will load the target of any `<a>` tag with the `rel="colorbox"` attribute in your colorbox whether the link be in your main page or in your colorbox content.